# Significant difference of liquidity pool data in different sources

Tags: liquidity-provider

For an example: APE/ETH 0.3% pool

There are different data of TVL in
https://info.uniswap.org/#/pools/0xac4b3dacb91461209ae9d41ec517c2b9cb1b7daf
and
https://etherscan.io/address/0xac4b3dacb91461209ae9d41ec517c2b9cb1b7daf
, even the data from uniswap app indicates that the pool is closed
https://app.uniswap.org/#/pool/204879?chain=mainnet
which data source is the most reliable?